# Придаточные изъяснительные?

Tags: синтаксис

Я определила следующие выделенные придаточные как изъяснительные, но сомневаюсь.

(1) *Я отправил запрос в другие города, **не было ли похожих преступлений**.*

Как надо задавать вопрос? "Я отправил запрос о чем?"

(2а) *Похоже, **что совещание только что закончилось**.*

(2б) *Жалко, **что вы поздно пришли**.*

Если убрать союз *что*, они будут породолжать быть придаточными изъяснительными? 
*Похоже, совещание только что закончилось. / Жалко, поздно пришли.*

(3) *Он сказал ей, что приедет генерал, так пусть комнату уберет, пол помоет **и главное чтоб не вздумала щи варить**.*

Насколько я понимаю *пусть уберет / помоет* это русский императив. 
Но как надо рассматривать *чтоб не вздумала щи варить*? Тоже как приказ/повелевание *даже не думай щи варить*!? 
Или это придаточное изъяснительное "*он сказал  ей, чтобы она не вздумала щи варить*"?
С другой стороны у меня чувство, что это могло бы быть придаточное цели с глаголом в сослагательном наклонении (*чтобы не вздумала*)

Исправьте, пожалуйста, если не права! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1) **СПП, придаточное изъяснительное**: Я отправил  в другие города **запрос**, не было ли похожих преступлений. (Обычно придаточное в подобных предложениях следует за опорным словом). БСП: Я отправил запрос в другие города: не было ли похожих преступлений?

Похожие примеры:

Позже мне пришлось несколько раз отвечать на вопрос, не было ли в его поведении в эти дни чего-нибудь необычного. А теперь задаю себе вопрос: не было ли у меня в роду еврейской бабушки?

2) При отсутствии союза ЧТО   "похоже", "жалко" скорее являются **вводными словами.**

3) Он сказал ей, что (1) приедет генерал,   так пусть комнату уберет, пол помоет и (2) главное чтоб не вздумала щи варить.

Здесь **две изъяснительные части с союзами ЧТО и ЧТОБЫ**. Первая часть состоит из трех предложений, два из которых в форме повелительного наклонения. Союз ЧТОБЫ - изъяснительный, выражает ирреальную модальность  (он сказал, чтобы...).

Comment: дорогая Sibylla, простите, еще пример:
"Она ела всё подряд. И вообще было непохоже, чтобы она сидела на диете." 
Правильно, если я определю "чтобы она сидела на диете" как изъяснительное придаточное? сбивает немного "чтобы" + "л-форма". Неужели это сосл. накл.?

Comment: Да, это изъяснительное придаточное, союз ЧТОБЫ выражает ирреальную модальность, опорное слово с отрицанием имеет значение недостоверности, неуверенности, сомнения, например: Не похоже (маловероятно), чтобы он на это согласился. Эту же мысль можно выразить в изъявительном наклонении: Вряд ли он на это согласится.

Comment: @Sibylla, мое понимание:   Он сказал ей, что приедет генерал, так (1) пусть комнату уберет, пол помоет и (2) главное чтоб не вздумала щи варить. (1) и (2) логически следует из того, что приедет генерал. Разве не так?

Comment: Разве "чтоб" здесь - предлог? Вот похожий пример из Нацкорпуса: "Ты этим делом не занимаешься, так что пропади. И чтобы я тебя не видел!"  Николай Леонов. Лекарство от жизни (2001)