# Трудная грамматика сложного предложения, помогите разобраться

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

Это старый вопрос (2016 год), и трудное предложение я взяла оттуда:

***(1) Он сказал ей, (2) что приедет генерал, (3) так пусть комнату уберет, пол помоет и (4) главное чтоб не вздумала щи варить.***

Автор спрашивала про изъяснительные отношения. Ответ был дан, но, как я думаю, **неточный**:

"*Здесь две изъяснительные части с союзами ЧТО и ЧТОБЫ. Первая часть состоит из трех предложений, два из которых в форме повелительного наклонения. Союз ЧТОБЫ — изъяснительный, выражает ирреальную модальность (он сказал, чтобы...)"*.

Ою этом было сказано **в комментарии**: Мое понимание: Он сказал ей, что приедет генерал, так (1) пусть комнату уберет, пол помоет и (2) главное чтоб не вздумала щи варить. (1) и (2) логически следует из того, что приедет генерал. Разве не так?

Теперь я вижу, что предложения (3) и (4) связаны между собой и следуют из предложения (2).

**Вопросы:**

Вероятно, (3) и 4) однородны, а не (2) и (4).

Какое наклонение у предложения (4)? По смыслу вроде бы это императив?

"Главное" не обособляется, а почему?

Как сделать разбор этого предложения (тип отношений, виды связи и всё такое)?

**У меня пока не получается,** подскажите хотя бы что-нибудь. И такие задания дают иностранным студентам!

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/425111/Придаточные-изъяснительные](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/425111/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)